# Vb net update statement issue

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have vb.net project for insert and update values in SQL server.It has sql code as below:

```
    Public Sub insert_customer_new(ByVal customer_id As Integer, ByVal work_state As Integer)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into customer_tbl (customer_id , work_state ) values (@customer_id, @work_state )", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("customer_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customer_id
    cmd.Parameters.Add("work_state", SqlDbType.Int).Value = work_state
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close()
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    cmd = Nothing
End Sub
```

And then

```
    Public Sub update_customer_new(ByVal customer_id As Integer, ByVal work_state As Integer)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update customer_tbl set  work_state = @work_state where customer_id = @customer_id ", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("customer_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customer_id
    cmd.Parameters.Add("work_state", SqlDbType.Int).Value = work_state
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close()
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    cmd = Nothing
End Sub
```

I use form ***Button.Click Event*** for `insert`

```
Private Sub insert_customer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles insert_customer.Click
    If customer_id.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("Pleas Enter Customer Number")
        customer_id.Focus()
    ElseIf state_txt.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("Pleas Enter The Start State Number ")
        state_txt.Focus()
    Else
        insert_customer_new(customer_id.Text, state_txt.Text)
        MsgBox("Insert Done !")
    End If

End Sub
```

And by same way I use form ***Button.Click Event*** for `update`

```
Private Sub update_state_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles update_state.Click
    If customer_id.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("Pleas Enter Customer Number For Update")
        customer_id.Focus()
    ElseIf state_txt.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("Pleas Enter The New State Number ")
        state_txt.Focus()
    Else
        update_customer_new(customer_id.Text, state_txt.Text)
        MsgBox("Update Done !")
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is some time the `update` statement does not perform. It gives no error, and the Procedure just skip this line for unknown reasons.
And it's happened about 10% of all cases that performed after application is published.

Comment: Please include more of the procedure so we can help debug. If there are no errors, it would be helpful to see as much of the code as possible to verify the procedure works as planned.

Comment: @StefanCrain 
well , i just check for null **customer_id**  text box by if statement and then after else  i use insert and update statement and then message box for confirmation , 
that's it ,
note : these cases happened in three different PC

Comment: That's nice, but let us see the code! It's impossible to debug further without, your insert / update statements look fine.

Comment: @StefanCrain  Thank you for replay 
I just added pictures of my code to the question , you can see my code

Comment: Sorry to sound like a broken record, but please include the relevant code and errors within your question as text. Linking to images hurts our ability to answer your question. Using images for code or error messages makes searching for similar errors impossible.

Comment: @StefanCrain OK here is my code with events i hope you will find something because i couldn't find any reason for this bug

Comment: did you check the serverside ? see if the command had reached the other end ?

Comment: try to catch the rendered value like this `Dim rows As Integer =  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and tell us the number you see.

Comment: @Abra001 ok it's returned **1** so it's reached the other end but sometime it doesn't

Comment: Try to change strategy and use dataset, check your connexion string, check if another datareader is hanging the connextion, if so, kill it because it prevents your query.

Comment: @Ahmed_programer supposedly you are overrunning sql connextion-pool toleration by opening/closing your connextion multiple times, it is a bad habbit, just try to reopen it once in a while.

Comment: @Abra001 OK thank you for your help i will check this out